# Trigger :visited state (make links purple) when browsing in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, browser-history, muon

In my Electron app I have a webview. If I click a link (e.g. on Google) and then move back, the link turns not purple, like in normal browsers.

Can I activate this behaviour in Electron too? Or do it programmatically, if I would store the browsing history by myself?

I guess it is somehow connected that the [history support in Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7186) is not yet the best?

Would this maybe possible with [Muon](https://github.com/brave/muon) fork of Electron?

Comment: Definitely let me know if that answer doesn't do it for you, or if you need more help with it :) It should be completely reliable, but I don't know your use case I can't verify that.

Comment: @Clonkex I my case it will be a real history, in extreme cases for with a year of daily browsing. So I am worried about the scaling …

Comment: I hadn't considered scalability; I've edited my answer with extra information (and made a slight performance improvement by moving `window.location.href` outside the loops).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the comments at about line 16 of [this file](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/df3f0a45164ff990e7b94bc7aa485b4659280755/lib/browser/api/navigation-controller.js), the Electron guys/girls have created their own navigation solution. It would seem this doesn't handle `a:visited` properly.

Instead, we can easily create our own solution. Add the following function to all of your renderer scripts and ensure you put `simuHistory();` at the start of every page:

```js
function simuHistory() {
    var localstorageSimuHistory = localStorage.getItem('simuHistory');
    var simuHistory = localstorageSimuHistory ? JSON.parse(localstorageSimuHistory) : [];
    var found = false;
    var windowHref = window.location.href;
    for(let i=0;i<simuHistory.length;i++) {
        if(simuHistory[i] == windowHref) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found === false) {
        simuHistory[simuHistory.length] = windowHref;
        localStorage.setItem('simuHistory', JSON.stringify(simuHistory));
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        for(let h=0;h<simuHistory.length;h++) {
            if(elements[i].href == simuHistory[h]) {
                elements[i].className += ' visited';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```css
.visited {
    color: purple;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to include the CSS (or want it all self-contained), you could replace this line:

```js
elements[i].className += ' visited';
```

...with this line:

```js
elements[i].style.color = 'purple';
```

---

### Scalability

The TL;DR is that unless you have more than around 25,000 fairly long unique URLs in your app, you don't need to worry about scalability.

The visited URLs are stored in `localStorage`. This is limited in size, and therefore limited in the number of URLs we can store. I believe in Electron this is limited to around 5MB. I tested performance by adding 25,000 additional URLs to the `simuHistory` array using the following code:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
    simuHistory[simuHistory.length] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
}
```

The URL was chosen because it was fairly long. The random number on the end actually affects nothing at all; I just included it to add some extra length. Then I timed running `simuHistory()` on my crappy slow laptop (with no SSD):

```
25,000 URLs == ~210ms
 1,000 URLs == ~13ms
```

In my opinion that's plenty fast for nearly any Electron app, but it depends on your use case as to how many URLs you might end up with.

Comment: Thanks! At least this makes clear that out of the box, it is not possible. I would love to use the real :visited state (a `check-visited-state` event would be wonderful), but I suspect it will not be possible.

Comment: @flori I did spend a fair amount of time trying to find a way to get `:visited` to work normally but I couldn't do it :( It might be worth filing it as a bug for electron. Also, when you say "a `check-visited-state` event would be wonderful", are you hinting I might add something to my code? ;) I'd be totally happy to add some kind of event but I don't know what an event like that would do.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Also regarding the Scaling. No, the `check-visited-state` event idea was not about your code.